# How to force MassTransit to update queue settings for exisitng AWS SQS queues?

Tags: masstransit

I am tryng to update our existing consumer SQS queues with new settings. In this case we need to change all queue TTLs to the maximum of 14 days (for both normal queues, error and DLQ queues).

After much searching around I found a code that seems like it can do that:

```
cfg.QueueAttributes.Add(QueueAttributeName.MessageRetentionPeriod, 1209600);
cfg.SendTopology.ConfigureErrorSettings = settings => settings.QueueAttributes.Add(QueueAttributeName.MessageRetentionPeriod, 1209600);
cfg.SendTopology.ConfigureDeadLetterSettings = settings => settings.QueueAttributes.Add(QueueAttributeName.MessageRetentionPeriod, 1209600);
```

However when building against existing queues it doesnt seem to update the settings.

Here is my full MassTransit setup:

```
services.AddMassTransit(x =>
{
    x.AddAmazonSqsMessageScheduler();
    x.AddConsumers(assembliesWithConsumers.ToArray());
    x.UsingAmazonSqs((context, cfg) =>
    {
        cfg.UseAmazonSqsMessageScheduler();

        cfg.Host("aws", h =>
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(mtSettings.AccessKey))
            {
                h.AccessKey(mtSettings.AccessKey);
            }

            if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(mtSettings.SecretKey))
            {
                h.SecretKey(mtSettings.SecretKey);
            }

            h.Scope($"{mtSettings.Prefix}-{mtSettings.Environment}", true);
            var sqsConfig = !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(mtSettings.SqsServiceUrl)
                ? new AmazonSQSConfig() { ServiceURL = mtSettings.SqsServiceUrl }
                : new AmazonSQSConfig()
                    { RegionEndpoint = RegionEndpoint.GetBySystemName(mtSettings.Region) };

            h.Config(sqsConfig);

            var snsConfig = !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(mtSettings.SnsServiceUrl)
                ? new AmazonSimpleNotificationServiceConfig()
                    { ServiceURL = mtSettings.SnsServiceUrl }
                : new AmazonSimpleNotificationServiceConfig()
                    { RegionEndpoint = RegionEndpoint.GetBySystemName(mtSettings.Region) };

            h.Config(snsConfig);
        });

        cfg.QueueAttributes.Add(QueueAttributeName.MessageRetentionPeriod, 1209600);
        cfg.SendTopology.ConfigureErrorSettings = settings => settings.QueueAttributes.Add(QueueAttributeName.MessageRetentionPeriod, 1209600);
        cfg.SendTopology.ConfigureDeadLetterSettings = settings => settings.QueueAttributes.Add(QueueAttributeName.MessageRetentionPeriod, 1209600);

        cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context, new BusEnvironmentNameFormatter(mtSettings.Environment));
    });
});
```

Does anyone know how to force SQS queues settings update with MassTransit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MassTransit will not update settings on existing queues or topics. The only way to get settings applied is to delete the queue or topic, after which MassTransit will recreate it with the configured settings.